# variable within a case expression oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following:

```
SELECT name,
       listagg(
               CASE length(TRIM(regexp_substr(lower(docs),
                       'process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*final activity|$)',
                                              1, 1, 'i', 1)))
                   WHEN 0 THEN
                       lower(docs)
                   ELSE
                       regexp_substr(lower(docs),
                        'process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*final activity|$)',
                                     1, 1, 'i', 1)
                   END, '. '
           )              AS final_doc
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
     name
```

I don't want to repeat the regular expression: `'process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*final activity|$)'`. I just want to define it once and use it. Or preferrably, I don't want this entire line duplicated: `regexp_substr(lower(docs), 'process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*final activity|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)`. How can I do that? Version is 19c

Comment: You could define it in a CTE or sub-query.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the `'i`' flag if you're converting the field to lowercase via `LOWER()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  *`Common Table expression`*(**`WITH..AS`**) in such a way that

```sql
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT m.*, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(docs,
                      'process\s+explanation\s*:\s*(.*?)(\.\s*final activity|$)',
                       1,
                       1,
                      'i',
                       1) AS rgs
   FROM my_table m
   
)
SELECT name,
       LISTAGG(CASE length(TRIM(rgs))
                 WHEN 0 THEN
                  lower(docs)
                 ELSE
                  rgs
               END,
               '. ') AS final_doc
  FROM t
 GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Great! what does `m.*` mean?

Comment: oh I get it it means all columns

Comment: just an alias to represent the table. In this case it's compulsory(for Oracle DB) to define all columns along with an extra column @jamespow

Comment: how does the performance compare to the original solution. Is it slower or approximately the same?